# How to add a loop in a game

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to write a basic cause and effect game. So far I've managed to display an image of a rocket on the screen (appers randomly on the x axles) and when touched launches. The program works fine but I want the rocket to reappear (loop 10 times), can anyone give me  some guidance on how I can achieve this.

I have attached the code from my scene.m below...

```
#import "MyScene.h"

  @implementation MyScene

  @import AVFoundation;

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        /* Setup your scene here */

        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor whiteColor];

        SKSpriteNode *rocket1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"rocket.png"];
        CGRect rocket1frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
       [rocket1 setSize:rocket1frame.size];
        rocket1.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 100);

        [self addChild:rocket1];

        _ship = rocket1;
     }
    return self;
   }

   -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   {
        CGPoint currentLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self];
       CGPoint previousLocation = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInNode:self];
    CGRect shipRect = _ship.frame;
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(shipRect, previousLocation))
    {
         CGPoint lvPosition = CGPointMake(_ship.position.x - (previousLocation.x -     currentLocation.x), _ship.position.y);
        _ship.position = lvPosition;

        SKAction *sound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"slideup.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO];
        SKAction *moveNode = [SKAction moveByX:lvPosition.x y:3000.0 duration:3.0];

        [_ship runAction: sound];
        [_ship runAction: moveNode];




    }
}



@end;
```

Comment: do you want it to reappear after the old rocket appear and move then disappear?

Comment: I don't see randoms in your code

Comment: Yes, i would like a new rocket to appear after the old rocket has launched and disappeared from the screen.

Comment: sorry, forget that I mentioned about the random part, I added that into a later version of my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
        CGPoint currentLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self];
        CGPoint previousLocation = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInNode:self];
        CGRect shipRect = _ship.frame;
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(shipRect, previousLocation))
        {
            [self launch:10 p1:currentLocation p2:previousLocation rect1:shipRect];
        }
}

-(void)launch:(int)count p1:(CGPoint) currentLocation p2:(CGPoint) previousLocation rect1:(CGRect) shipRect
{
    CGPoint lvPosition = CGPointMake(_ship.position.x - (previousLocation.x - currentLocation.x), _ship.position.y);
    _ship.position = lvPosition;

    SKAction *sound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"slideup.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO];
    SKAction *moveNode = [SKAction moveByX:lvPosition.x y:3000.0 duration:3.0];

    [_ship runAction: sound];
    [_ship runAction: moveNode completion:^{

            if (count)
                [self launch:count-- p1:currentLocation p2:previousLocation rect1:shipRect];               
           }];
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I've added your code but recive a "variable block is not assignable(missing block type specifier" to this part of the code.......if (count)
                [self launch:count-- p1:currentLocation p2:previousLocation rect1:shipRect];               
           }];